# plt.loglog vs. np.log - How to achieve the same axes scaling with np.log?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code has to achieve two aims. First, it has to apply the logarithm on both the x- and y-axis of some data and compute its slope via `scipy.stats.linregress`. Second, I would like to plot the resulting log-log transformation of this data using axes that scale to 10^x (just like `plt.loglog` *only visually* scales the data).

Here is my code:

```
PLE_list = []
Ideal_frequency = np.loadtxt("...") # Load a one-column file (log already applied) containing numerical values

Subjects = ["Subject1"]

for Subject in Subjects:
    Data = np.loadtxt("...") # Load another one-column file containing numerical values
    Data = np.log(Data)
    
    PLE = stats.linregress(Ideal_frequency, Data, alternative="less")
    PLE_list.append(PLE[0])
    print(f"{'%.7f' % PLE[0]}")
    
    plt.plot(Ideal_frequency, Data, linewidth=2.5)
    
plt.show()
```

The result of this code looks like this:
[image]
However, I would like the visual result to look like this, such as when loading data without appying the logarithm on it, but using `plt.loglog` instead of `plt.plot`:

[image]

It is possible to change the code of `np.log(xyz)`such that is scales the x- and y-axis identical to `plt.loglog`? In other words: is it possible to change my code in order to achieve the 10^x scaling of `plt.loglog` without actually using `plt.loglog`, but `plt.plot`?

The problem currently is that I have to load apply `np.log` on my data to compute the correct slope via `sp.stats.linregress`, but then plot the non-log data with `plt.loglog` to achieve the 10^x axes scaling.

Comment: Don’t take the log of the data before doing the plotting, just do it for the fit.

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple and nice idea indeed! However, I still wonder: how can I change or adjust np.log() so that the visual scaling/plotting of the data by plt.plot looks identical to plotting non-log data with plt.loglog? Is what I try to achieve even possible?